# Hitting docker rate limit without pulling at all

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a computer that is running docker. Now I get the error toomanyrequests when I try to pull an image. The twist is, I get this error if Docker is just running and I do not pull anything. So by waiting I never get to pull anything, except if I change my IP. If I get a fresh IP, I can pull without a problem. But after a few hours, I cannot pull anymore from the IP that the computer that is running Docker is using.

To my knowledge, I do not have any other software running that should provoke a pull. Is there anything from Docker itself, that contact docker hub and is causing the rate limit to kick-in. I just have 3 simple services running in Docker: A web proxy, a database and keycload. This is on a VM running Ubuntu 22.04.

There are no other machine on my network that are running Docker. If I start other machines and start Docker there, this problem does not occur. For example, I can start Docker Desktop on another machine and pull lots of stuff and leave it running, I do not get toomanyrequests.

Can anyone offer an explanation what is causing this? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are some machines logged in, and others not logged in? That could explain the difference.

Comment: No. No login. And even if - why should it matter, if there are no pulls, why is there a toomanyrequests error if there should be NO requests.